# Shortening bitwise equations

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, xor, assignment-operator

Similar to how plus and minus can be shortened thusly:

```
$x = $x + 5;
```

becomes

```
$x += 5;
```

Can you do a similar thing with bitwise operators? For example when applying XOR would the following be valid?

```
$x = $x ^ 1;
```

becomes

```
$x ^= 1;
```

Having tested this simple script it seems to work, however is it right to use this, or am I way off track here?

Comment: @MihaiIorga: The term is *assignment* :)

Comment: Assignment .. assignment :)

Comment: If you're going to negative the question at least comment why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php (first comment)

```
See the Arithmetic Operators page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
Assignment    Same as:
$a += $b      $a = $a + $b    Addition
$a -= $b      $a = $a - $b    Subtraction
$a *= $b      $a = $a * $b    Multiplication
$a /= $b      $a = $a / $b    Division
$a %= $b      $a = $a % $b    Modulus

See the String Operators page(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
$a .= $b      $a = $a . $b       Concatenate

See the Bitwise Operators page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)
$a &= $b      $a = $a & $b     Bitwise And
$a |= $b      $a = $a | $b     Bitwise Or
$a ^= $b      $a = $a ^ $b     Bitwise Xor
$a <<= $b     $a = $a << $b    Left shift
$a >>= $b     $a = $a >> $b    Right shift
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's mentioned in **[this comment on the Assignment Operators page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#40084)**

> ```
> Assignment    Same as:
> $a += $b     $a = $a + $b    Addition
> $a -= $b     $a = $a - $b     Subtraction
> $a *= $b     $a = $a * $b     Multiplication
> $a /= $b     $a = $a / $b    Division
> $a %= $b     $a = $a % $b    Modulus
>
> See the String Operators page(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
> $a .= $b     $a = $a . $b       Concatenate
>
> See the Bitwise Operators page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)
> $a &= $b     $a = $a & $b     Bitwise And
> $a |= $b     $a = $a | $b      Bitwise Or
> $a ^= $b     $a = $a ^ $b       Bitwise Xor
> $a <<= $b     $a = $a << $b     Left shift
> $a >>= $b     $a = $a >> $b      Right shift
> ```